# specific rank request

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a dataset queried from an oracle table, column TS means test sequence, DATE TIME is the start of measurement time, OP means test operation, STATUS is the status of the operation, and RUN_TPYE means the type of the event.
I want to define the date time of OP='PRE2' while STATUS='START' as loading_date, 
there are 6 loading_date in the sample, now I want to rank them partition by OP, RUN_TYPE and order by TS, I hope to assign each OP between rank_(n-1) and rank_n with the loading_date at rank_(n-1).
Anybody can help me on this purpose?

[image]

In case the pic didn't display, here I paste the dataset:

```
TS   DATE TIME       OP    STATUS   RUN_TYPE LOADING_DATE
24  7/9/2018 15:39  PRE2    START   NBR      7/9/2018
23  7/6/2018 3:34   FIN2    PASS    NB       7/5/2018
22  7/6/2018 1:17   CRT2    PASS    NB       7/5/2018
21  7/5/2018 22:25  FNC2    PASS    NBR      7/5/2018
20  7/5/2018 12:22  CAL2    PASS    NBR      7/5/2018
19  7/5/2018 10:21  PRE2    PASS    NBR      7/5/2018
18  7/5/2018 8:01   PRE2    START   NBR      
17  7/5/2018 7:56   FNC2    10463   NBR      7/2/2018
16  7/4/2018 9:57   CAL2    PASS    NBR      7/2/2018
15  7/4/2018 7:01   PRE2    PASS    NBR      7/2/2018
14  7/4/2018 3:39   PRE2    START   NBR      7/2/2018
13  7/4/2018 3:28   FNC2    10463   NBR      7/2/2018
12  7/3/2018 5:51   CAL2    PASS    NBR      7/2/2018
11  7/3/2018 2:49   PRE2    PASS    NBR      7/2/2018
10  7/2/2018 23:20  PRE2    START   NBR
9   7/2/2018 23:13  FNC2    10463   NBR      6/29/2018
7   6/29/2018 22:34 CAL2    PASS    NBR      6/29/2018
6   6/29/2018 19:33 PRE2    PASS    NBR      6/29/2018
5   6/29/2018 16:10 PRE2    START   NBR
4   6/29/2018 16:08 FNC2    10280   NB       6/28/2018
3   6/28/2018 20:06 CAL2    PASS    NB       6/28/2018
2   6/28/2018 17:05 PRE2    PASS    NB       6/28/2018
1   6/28/2018 13:13 PRE2    START   NB
```

Comment: Could you detail what you have tried to achieve this?

Comment: Thanks, DKyleo, I added my desired in column 'LOADING_DATE'. My intention is to set DATE TIME with OP='PRE2' and STATUS='START' as LOADING_DATE for other OPs behind OP='PRE2' and STATUS='START' and ends at the next OP='PRE2' and STATUS='START'. for ex. LOADING_DATE for TS=2,3,4 equals to the DATE TIME of TS=1;  LOADING_DATE for TS=6,7,9 equals to the DATE TIME of TS=5, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to count the number of rows that have `op = 'PRE2'` up to any given row.  You can use analytic functions:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when op = 'PRE2' THEN 1 else 0 end) over (order by datetime) as rank_
from t;
```